# Why AWS EB environment variables show ? mark for Japanese text

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables

The AWS EB(Elastic Beanstalk) environment variable is working fine for English text but showing an interrogative mark for Japanese text as shown in the below image.

[image: Problem-Image]

How to resolve this problem, any help will be appraisable.
Thank you in advance.